# Low noise digital family

Tags: oscillator

I want to build a battery operated low noise audio VCO.

With current knowledge I could use discrete transistors, op-apms, 555, HC4046 ,  or a simple NAND-circuit. Which option would produce least amount of noise?

**Update:**

The application is a synth. The waveform generator should be discrete electronics. (not MCU-generated).

With noise I mean noise as in white/pink which all semiconductors / resistors produce. (diode noise generator for example). Harmonic overtones are not a problem.

Comment: This is probably too broad. You can create a good low noise circuit with opamps. You can create a good low noise circuit with discrete transistors. You can also create bad, noisy circuits with both. What kind of waveform do you want out?

Comment: Square. Should I take your answer as digital cicruits (HC etc) are discouraged from noise perspective?

Comment: What type of voltage control do you need i.e. linear or exponential control. This makes a big difference.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that info, @user247245. While you're at it, define what you mean with "low-noise". Phase noise? correlated noise? uncorrelated noise?

Comment: @Andyaka,  log would probably make most sense, as in 1V/octave.

Comment: Ah the more complex route. So you are building a synthesizer then? How many octaves? You need to be much more free with the specification if you want a decent answer.

Comment: @user247245 you might also want to specify whether you really need *all* possible frequencies of your range (which you should specify), ie. continuous tuning, or whether a "grid" of frequencies is enough (which you'd then have to specify). A discrete set of frequencies might make a digital implementation a lot easier!

Comment: I wonder if the easiest and most stable route would be use a microcontroller. Sample the control voltage with an ADC and generate the appropriate waveform. Unless of course analogue sounds better... ;)

Comment: @Colin__s yeah, I was thinking the same (kinda hinting at that, but then again, I feel like I'm pushing µCs too much here), but think about it: let's say you get a decent, 16bit ADC for that, doesn't give you all that fine a grid over the ~10 octaves of human hearing, does it? (maybe it does, that's around 165 frequencies per octave – probably good enough).Then again, OP really never spec'ed how much frequency accuracy or stability or resolution is necessary, so maybe you should just post that as an answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The update to the question now precludes it from being an answer. I still think it the most sensible route though.

Comment: To be concise: Does a 555/7555 or NAND produce more noise than a good audio op-amp in the human audio spectrum?

Comment: @user247245 define what you mean with "produce noise", and we can discuss that. An opamp as is isn't an oscillator, so you're definitively referring to some specific opamp-based circuit, which you also don't specify. So, this is really impossible to answer.

Comment: @Colin__s yes, it's really an arbitrary restriction, and I don't see any good reason for that.

Comment: @user247245 why do you preclude MCUs? Is there any particular reason why you want to make this hard for you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, MCU's are great but I want an all analog application. To compress my question, I'm asking for the S/N ratio or nV/Hz of let's say the HC14.

Comment: Ah ok, but the N in S/N is still "Noise", and I'm not sure what that entices? the ripple on the "highs" and "lows" of the square wave? The random jitter (can be modeled as added voltage at the transition times), or the non-perfect rectangular slope? I really don't see how a HC **logic** IC is any more or less analog than an MCU, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, from the original question about generating a waveform from either an op-amp or some gates; they can both be modulated with analogue inputs, which MCU's can't, where the modding is based on code. I'm asking for the added noise in the PN-layers, if they differ in S/N between a low-noise op-amp and a simple gate. Transition noise should be taken into account. If it's considered noise and now slew-rate, which probably would be out of audiable range.

Comment: MCUs can implement any modulation, as long as the bandwidth fits within the Nyquist bandwidth they can represent (source: I earn my rent doing software defined radio), if you convert the analog waveforms to digital first. I think you might be on to something. Please expland what you're referring to by **editing** your question to include the info you're giving in your comment. Still, you're comparing "a single gate" (I presume that means logic?) with "an opamp", and that's like comparing apples with self-driving cars, or so. I really don't know what to make of your question.

Comment: I know MCU's can be great. Sometimes. I'll try the HC-concept. I'll evaluate the noise as they add up to 20 oscillators in parallell.

Answer (score 3):

> @Andyaka, log would probably make most sense, as in 1V/octave

Here is a design for an exponential (1 volt per octave) voltage to frequency converter from Linear Technology: -

[image]

[LT page](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1587) that this circuit came from.

If you need a sine wave then it becomes trickier. The circuit above produces a sawtooth output and of course this can be filtered to make a sine wave but with the ability to shift the frequency you need a filter that can track that frequency. This can be achieved by a voltage controlled filter. Alternatively you can use a PLL to produce a synchronized much-higher frequency and use this to clock a 10th order switched-capacitor low pass filter that does the sawtooth to sine conversion. Not impossible especially as you also have the control voltage to help modify PLL VCO component values thus giving you probably up to 5 octave control.

If you just wanted a linear V to F and didn't care about waveform shape it's much easier.

> I want to build a battery operated low noise audio VCO

You can easily make +/- 15 volt supplies from virtually any battery but what this really comes down to is, how big is your battery and how long do you want it to last?

Comment: You can add a thresholding comparator to translate sawtooth to square, in case that's what OP needs. OP also promised me to edit the question to add more specs a couple minutes ago. Hasn't really delivered, though :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's really hard to find people asking really good questions LOL. I shall write to my member of parliament about this ;)

Comment: Just read the question again without the bias of personal preferences.

Comment: @user247245 I wasn't aiming my humour at you.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of under the impression the sarcasm was directed at me :) Ah, right, I forgot about the switched cap ICs you can buy. I actually had one of these as adjustable anti-aliasing filter in a DAQ board I developed a few years ago; Maxim MAX297, or so, gotta look that up

Comment: Ah, yes, MAX297, but the problem was that it leaked the switching clock, so I had to add another RC LPF to get rid of that -.- which of course interfered with my ability to have a widely adaptable AA filter :(

Comment: No sarcasm. I try my best to be friendly here. I don't think the question was that shitty in its original state. Maby I should elaborate on that I'm asking for the internal noise of the silicon of 555s and NAND's.

Comment: Linear tech do some awesome switched cap filters and they're much more sophisticated than my sense of humour LOL

Comment: But I'm afraid they communicate in all-caps? ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to build a battery operated low noise audio VCO.

So far, so good. I take it "audio" means the following:

- Audio Frequency: 0.02 – 20 kHz
- Typical Audio amplitudes: 0.4 – 1 V
- waveform must be a sine

Low noise will mean both:

- Low phase noise
- high frequency stability
- as little non-sinusoidals in the signal

> With current knowledge i could use discrete transistors, op-apms, 555 or a simple NAND-circuit. Which option would produce least amount of noise?

You can't use a NAND circuit or a 555. These give you non-sinusoidal waveforms. A square wave, for example, has its fundamental frequency as spectral content, but also every odd multiple of that – so 3x, 5x, 7x that frequency, and so on. Since your upper frequency limit is much larger than 3x your lower frequency, you can't simply filter out the harmonics. So this *can't* work.

The 555 was introduced in 1971. That is now 46 years ago. The 55 is not suited for anything that you'd consider High Fidelity. It really never was. It was designed to be an easy-to-use timer IC. Not as a high-quality oscillator.

So, what you need is something that can either select a different set of filters to generate a sine from a non-sine periodic signal (e.g. a square wave), or something that modifies a sinusoidal oscillation.

The latter is what you'd normally buy as VCO. You can build VCOs yourself, using tank circuits and whatnot (that's probably what you meant with "discrete transistors"), but these circuits are usually very hard to make long-term stable – as soon as anything heats up, the frequency changes. A fresh draft of air – changes in frequency. Cat walks by from the left to the right – change in frequency.

The former, a set of filters allowing you to select exactly those harmonics you need from a square wave, is of course a bit of a hassle. In essence, for every octave you need to generate, you'd need to have a filter on its own.

Usually, you combine these two ideas:

- The reference oscillation (and hence, stability) comes from a square wave oscillator, and
- The sine shape is generated by letting something oscillate harmonically, disciplining that oscillation's period by the period of the reference.

The typical way of implementing that is using what is called a *Phase Locked Loop* (PLL) to control the voltage of a not-very-stable VCO. If the VCO is faster than it should be (ie. faster than the reference), then the control voltage is lowered, and vice versa.

You could, for example, buy a PLL IC, generate the reference frequency you want with any square wave generator (ie. a CMOS counter-based oscillator circuit, or a, as much as I hate to say that, since it'd still be a lousy reference, CMOS variant of the 555), and build a tank circuit oscillator using discrete transistors, letting the PLL IC control the control voltage.

You can also, and that's what I'd personally tend to, do the same, but use a microcontroller to generate the reference (internally, i.e. simply a counter in software), and use the same microcontroller to implement the PLL (a counter that counts the oscillations produced by your VCO circuit, compares that number to the "should be" number of the internal oscillations, and adjusts the output voltage accordingly).

Comment: Thank you for your verbose answer, however with noise i mean noise. Not harmonic overtones or frequency stability.

Comment: @user247245 you're not making any sense. Phase noise is noise. Overtones are unwanted signal that adds up to your desired signal. So, noise. If you don't mean that, you might want to *define* what you consider noise, because, as a communication engineer, it's not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post. To my knowledge there's a vast difference between noise and overtones. Unwanted overtones are more similar to distortion. Noise is all frequencies at the same time. IMHO, I think you're wrong on this one.

Comment: "noise" is exactly what *you* define to be noise. I agree, I'd call the overtones distortion if I was looking for a sine, too. But I might just as well count it to noise. "Noise is all frequencies at the same time": I think you might be thinking about *white noise*, but that's a very special, in fact, rare, but often assumed, type of noise.

Comment: Thank you for your input but i have to disagree with you. I can't see how noise can be a personal definition. Noise (pink/white/blue) adds noise. It's indifferent to the frequency of the origin, of which harmonic overtones or formants are not.

Comment: The usual definition is that noise is uncorrelated with the signal, distortion is correlated. So overtones are distortion while thermal noise is noise because it does not change with the signal. I would note that for synthesizers somewhat less then ideal waveshapes can actually be desired, and a triangle followed by a variable Q VCF is actually an interesting option as it means you can vary from a somewhat distorted sine to triangle with one knob.

Comment: @user247245 google "multiplicative noise"; you'll notice noise isn't even always additive, like you claim. Sorry. I really don't want to start an argument on semantics here, but if you require a "low-noise" something, it's always a good idea to define what noise is to you, and how it's relevant to your overall application.

Comment: @user247245 phase noise, cycle-to-cycle variations in the period of the signal, should be a much greater concern than white or pink, if you're making something to listen to.  If "audio" is just your frequency range, that's not necessarily so. A relaxation oscillator has more phase noise than almost any other type. Your mentioning HC4046 means you're at least considering a PLL. TI has a good app note on PLLs using (at least part of) the HC4046: "Application Report SCAA088–March 2008, Generating Low Phase-Noise Clocks for Audio Data Converters from Low Frequency Word Clock"